# REST API correct URL structure to load entity but with different options

Tags: rest

Here is dilemma I have, not sure how to design it pretty.

Pretend I have `/customer` endpoint

Customer should be retreived in following ways:

1. By `key` (numeric)
2. By `id` (alphanumeric)
3. By `id` with `direction` (enum)

So, if it was just "by key" requirement I would create following:

1. GET `/customer/1234`
2. POST `/customer/1234`
3. DELETE `/customer/1234`

But since I have additional requirements - I'm not sure how to structure `GET`. What comes to mind:

1. GET `/customer?key=1234`
2. GET `/customer?id=ABC`
3. GET `/customer?id=ABC&direction=next`

But I don't really like how it looks. Any clever ways to keep it "REST" but cover scenarios I listed for GETting single customer record?

Comment: If you don't want to use a query string, you can rename your endpoint to `/customer/search/{param}/{value}`. You can have it default to "by key", `/customer/{key}`

Comment: The query params look good to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**IDEALLY**, you need only one parameter to seek customer from GET. Everything else should be done like `filter` or `search` by passing query params.

For example, most of the time you use `id` in `customer/<id>`, but when you need any specific query params just design your server so you can evaluate this query:

`GET /customers?key=<key>&limit=1` or `GET /customers?key=<key>&direction=next&limit=1`.

The query params are not as bad as you think.

> Note that I followed **PURE RESTful API** rules, using `POST /customers/search is not the REST`

That's how I'd do this

Comment: thanks! Just evaluating ideas. `id` is just as common/important as `key` hence I wasn't so sure. I think I will go with `/customer` and query string. I don't think it's bad, I was just wondering what other people thinking

Comment: @katit The question is do you need to follow 'real' REST API or some hybrid.. you know. I used both in the past and both are working like a charm :)

Comment: It's our internal API with possibility to expose it to other parties later. Trying to make it more "mainstream", but yes, it will work either way. I tend to go with query string so it's consistent between differen kinds

Comment: @katit Cool. Good luck. Ask if any :)